# Dynamic Radio Button Control

Tags: android

Code ...{

```
private void createRadioButton() {

        final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
            ll.addView(rb[i]); 
            rb[i].setText("Test");
         }
         ll.addView(submit); 
          submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
                    ll.removeView(rb[i]); 
                }  
                ll.removeView(submit);
                Questions();
         }});   
    }
```

The issue i am having is that the radio buttons appear and the user can select any one. Being a beginner im sure i am not setting the radio buttons up correctly. The user is able to select all five buttons and then once selected they cant uncheck them either. The user should only be able to select one option from the five...how can i make this possable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must add the radio buttons to a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) and then the RadioGroup to the layout

I miss some information like what is submit, but your code should look like:

```
private void createRadioButton() {
    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
        rg.addView(rb[i]); //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead of the layout
        rb[i].setText("Test");
    }
    ll.addView(rg);//you add the whole RadioGroup to the layout
    ll.addView(submit); 
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
                rg.removeView(rb[i]);//now the RadioButtons are in the RadioGroup
            }  
            ll.removeView(submit);
            Questions();
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: @ShahzadImam How about setId()?

Comment: @spaaarky21 : Solved it a year ago.. thanx.

Comment: @MariLuna ll is the layout and Questions() should be a function in the class. they are taken directly from the question's code

Comment: What about sumbit? @maid450

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a RadioGroup in the layout file

```
<TableRow>
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/radiobuttons">
     </RadioGroup>
</TableRow>
```

and then programmatically add buttons to it:

```
public void makeRadioButtons(Vector tmpVector, int i,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp)
{
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
    rb.setText((String) tmpVector.elementAt(i));
    //rg is private member of class which refers to the radio group which you can find by id.
    rg.addView(rb, 0, lp);

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Im not using xml because i need to make these buttons dynamically as there could be 1,2 or 15 buttons created by the application.

Comment: im not sure how radio buttons or groups work at the moment. Do i add the button to the group and then display the group?

Comment: @Usmaan: Yes first add button to group and then display the whole group. For reference: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/RadioGroup1.html

Answer (score 3):

Your Layout.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

code

```
   RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);//not this RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
 rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
        rg.addView(rb[i]); 
        rb[i].setText("Test");
    }
```

hope this help you.