# android list view item with radio button still on

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button

I have list view, each row of it has a radion button, I want to select just one of the rows.

My problem is that I can select more than one item and the radion button still on even when I press it again, actually I had this problem three months ago and I solve it, now I tried the same solution but It unfortuntally didn't work
.

MY ADAPTER CODE

```
class AdapterRestaurantSelectOne extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Boolean> rb_status = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private List<Restaurant> restaurants = null;
    Context context;
    LinearLayout ll_CancelDone;
    public int positionNowSelected;

    public AdapterRestaurantSelectOne(Context context,
            List<Restaurant> restaurants, LinearLayout ll_CancelDone,
            RadioGroup radioGroup) {
        positionNowSelected = -1;
        this.context = context;
        this.restaurants = restaurants;
        this.ll_CancelDone = ll_CancelDone;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.size(); i++) {
            rb_status.add(false);
        }

    }

    public Restaurant getRestaurant() {
        return restaurants.get(positionNowSelected);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return restaurants.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return restaurants.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return restaurants.get(position).getID();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list_item_radiobutton, null);
        TextView tv_name = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_profile_list_item_radioButton_title);
        ImageView iv_image = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_profile_list_item_radiobutton_image);
        RadioButton rb_selected = (RadioButton) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.cb_profile_list_item_radioButton_radioButton);

        rb_selected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                rb_status.set(position, isChecked);
                boolean status = false;
                int i = 0;
                for (Boolean b : rb_status) {
                    if (b) {
                        status = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (status) {
                    Basket.setRestaurant(restaurants.get(i));
                    positionNowSelected = i;
                    ll_CancelDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    Basket.setRestaurant(null);
                    positionNowSelected = -1;
                    ll_CancelDone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        rb_selected.setChecked(rb_status.get(position));
        // rb_selected.setChecked(position == positionNowSelected);
        tv_name.setText(restaurants.get(position).getName());
        iv_image.setImageResource(restaurants.get(position).getImage());
        return vi;
```

Comment: You are not adding the Radio Buttons inside the Radio Group

Comment: should I do that? I don't think so, I have read a lot of threads here, no one said I have to use Radio Group

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565989/how-to-add-radio-buttons-to-radio-group, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669104/dynamic-radio-button-control, http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

Comment: It is not my case buddy, I am sure the answer doesn't need a radio groub

Comment: It is all about `getView` function with cycling and recycling

Comment: What's your list view's selection mode? Have you tried adding android:choiceMode="singleChoice" to your xml definition of the list view?

Comment: @npace yes I have already used singlechoich mode

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution my self, It is like this;

```
lv_allRestaurants.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View vuew,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (adapterAll2.getPositionNowSelected() == position) {
            adapterAll2.setPositionNowSelected(-1);
            adapterAll2.ll_CancelDone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            adapterAll2.setPositionNowSelected(position);
            adapterAll2.ll_CancelDone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        adapterAll2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Then the adapter is:

```
class AdapterRestaurantSelectOne extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Boolean> rb_status = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private List<Restaurant> restaurants = null;
    Context context;
    LinearLayout ll_CancelDone;
    public int positionNowSelected;

    public AdapterRestaurantSelectOne(Context context,
            List<Restaurant> restaurants, LinearLayout ll_CancelDone) {
        positionNowSelected = -1;
        this.context = context;
        this.restaurants = restaurants;
        this.ll_CancelDone = ll_CancelDone;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.size(); i++) {
            rb_status.add(false);
        }

    }

    public Restaurant getRestaurant() {
        return restaurants.get(positionNowSelected);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return restaurants.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list_item_radiobutton, null);
        }
        TextView tv_name = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_profile_list_item_radioButton_title);
        ImageView iv_image = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_profile_list_item_radiobutton_image);
        RadioButton rb_selected = (RadioButton) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.cb_profile_list_item_radioButton_radioButton);
        tv_name.setText(restaurants.get(position).getName());
        iv_image.setImageResource(restaurants.get(position).getImage());
        rb_selected.setChecked(position == positionNowSelected);
        return vi;
    }

    public int getPositionNowSelected() {
        return this.positionNowSelected;
    }

    public void setPositionNowSelected(int now) {
        this.positionNowSelected = now;
    }
}
```